# how to assign repeated message in protobuf-php, with proto3 syntax?

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, proto3

The .proto file defined:

```
message ResponseStatus {
    uint32 code = 1;
    string message = 2;
}
message DepositPaymentRequest {
    uint32 member_id = 1;
}
message DepositPaymentResponse {
    ResponseStatus status = 1;
    repeated DepositMethod methods = 2;
}
message DepositMethod {
    string method_name = 1;
    string payment_count = 2;
    repeated DepositPayment payments = 3;
}
message DepositPayment {
    uint32 payment_id = 1;
    string payment_name = 2;
    uint32 payment_money_min = 3;
    uint32 payment_money_max = 4;
}
```

My php code:

```
$status = [
    'code'    => 200,
    'message' => 'Success'
];
$responseStatus = new ResponseStatus($status);
$depositMethods = [
    [
         'name'  => 'name1',
         'count' => 1,
         'payments' => [
              [
                   'payment_id'        => 1,
                   'payment_name'      => 'name1',
                   'payment_money_min' => 10,
                   'payment_money_max' => 5000
              ]
         ]
    ]
];
$depositPaymentResponse = new DepositPaymentResponse();
$result = $depositPaymentResponse->setStatus($responseStatus)
                                         ->setMethods($depositMethods)
                                         ->serializeToString();
```

**actual:**
the $result no data, so how to assign repeated field ?

I try to use RepeatedField class like this:

```
$repeatedMethods = new RepeatedField(GPBType::MESSAGE, DepositMethod::class);
```

But I don't known how to use this, so i use array to assign but not success

Comment: Have you tried an array of instances of DepositMethod?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved it just like you said. and I referenced this issue:https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2686

Comment: @Tank, your link worked for me. Is there any new way of doing this currently?